# Counting possible configurations: more boxes than elements

Tags: combinatorics

How many ways are to place $N/2+1$ 'kids' in $N$ 'chairs'? ($N$ is odd but I have to compute the enter division.)

**Edit**: Maybe it is easier if I define it as:

- I want to place $n$ 'kids' in $2n+1$ 'chairs'.

Comment: If $N$ is odd, then $N/2+1$ isn't an integer. How do you define the half of a "kid" ?

Comment: I am studying spin configurations in atoms, that's why I have to compute the enter division (so no kids are hurt), I wanted to say, for $N=5$, $N/2+1=3$

Comment: Then why don't you just use the floor function? "$\lfloor N/2\rfloor +1$ kids" ?

Comment: Assuming that the chairs are distinct / order of sitting doesn't matter, we have $\dbinom{N}{\lfloor N/2\rfloor +1}$ ways to do this. If order of sitting matters, use permutations instead of combinations.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We have to pick the chairs we use: $\binom{N}{N/2+1}$ ways.
We have to pick the arrangement of people in the chairs we chose: $(N/2+1)!$ ways.

Therefore $\binom{N}{N/2+1} \times (N/2+1)! = \frac{N!}{(N/2-1)!}$ ways.

Comment: You correctly answered the original question.  It was changed twice after you answered it, which was not fair to you.

Comment: I'm sorry. You're right and you answered before.

Answer (score 3):

Choose seats in $\binom{2n+1}{n}$ ways, and arrange kids in those seats,

so $\;n!\binom{2n+1}{n}\;$ arrangements, or written as a permutation, $^{2n+1}P_n$

Comment: I think that ${2n+1 \choose n}$ will do!

Comment: @MarcC: Unless the kids are identical, you're wrong.

Comment: !! Why? I don't care about the order, no?

Comment: @MarcC: Of course you do (as I've mentioned in the previous comment - unless the kids are identical to each other).

Comment: Ok, so my mistake of using kids instead of balls. I don't care about the order.

Comment: @MarcC: So you should mention this in the question. It is a reasonable assumption that the kids are unique.

Comment: You are totally right.

Comment: @MarcC: Now that you've altered the question, this answer becomes obsolete, which is not really fair towards the user who has spent their time in writing it down properly. You should probably post the new version as a separate question, and leave this question in its previous version.

Comment: Such a mess am I. I leave it in the previous version and choosed the other answer as correct as he writed it before.

Comment: @barakmanos: Thanks for squaring up things while I was away. (+'s)

Comment: No problem :)  ...